# Suddenly extra hex string in <script> tags

Tags: javascript, tags

By accident I saw that a hex string is added to all `<script>` tags.
Example:

```
<script src='https://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp' 
    type="11c18651ae5f866771d68c33-text/javascript">
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
</script>
```

*Of course, I have done the normal procedure:*

1. I disabled all plugins
2. I emptied the `functions.php` file.
3. I activated/switched to the default theme `Twenty Seventeen`.

**--> Nothing changed!**

Each time I press F5 the hex string changes - as it would be the PHP session id. I don't want to post the URL here to avoid to be classified as a spammer.

Any idea what this can be as it doesn't make any sense? This came up in the past weeks.

Comment: Did you also try switching to a default theme?

Comment: Is this happening both when you're logged in and not? Have you tried from different devices to verify it's happening everywhere?

Comment: @WebElaine I am validating from time to time the page by https://validator.w3.org/ and it was the validator who was complaining. So, it's global in the internet and not locally in my environment/browser [where I see it of course as well]. As I mentioned, I don't want to be classified as spammer, is there a way I can provide you the URL privately if you think it helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Cloudflare `Rocket Loader` option which caused this. I disabled `Rocket Loader` and it has gone.

Edit: In the [Cloudflare support page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-) is this very clear note and it explains all:

[image]

So, before I validate the page I disable it in order to avoid useless warnings and then I turn it on again.